# put default image if there is no image using ACF

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using Wordpress ACF plugin and I have custom products section and I put a custom field for featured image and it's working perfect.

Now I want if there is no featured image inserted then show a default image, I am using the following code but its not working.

```
<? php
$category_image = get_field('fimage');
if ($category_image) {
  $category_image_url = $category_image['sizes']['product-thumb'];
}
if ($category_image_url) { ?>
 <img src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/timthumb.php?src=<?php echo $category_image['url']; ?>&w=300&h=250&zc=0" alt="<?php echo $category_image['name']; ?>" title="<?php echo $category_image['name']; ?>">
} else($category_image_url) { ?>
  <img src="http://www.staticwhich.co.uk/static/images/products/no-image/no-image-available.png" alt="<?php echo $category_image['name']; ?>" title="<?php echo $category_image['name']; ?>">
<? php } ?>
```

Comment: hey its error in your code change this   else($category_image_url) { just else {

Comment: still it is not working properly, if you want I can give you the link of page

Comment: try i paste my code and let  me know result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$category_image="";
$category_image_url="";
    $category_image = get_field('fimage');
    if($category_image){
        $category_image_url = $category_image['sizes']['product-thumb'];
    }
    if($category_image_url) { ?>
         <img src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/timthumb.php?src=<?php echo $category_image['url']; ?>&w=300&h=250&zc=0" alt="<?php echo $category_image['name']; ?>" title="<?php echo $category_image['name']; ?>">
    <?php
    } 
    else { ?>
       <img src="http://www.staticwhich.co.uk/static/images/products/no-image/no-image-available.png" alt="<?php echo $category_image['name']; ?>" title="<?php echo $category_image['name']; ?>">
                            <?php } ?>
```

Comment: not showing default image, still showing broken image sign

Comment: can you give me site link please?

Comment: where did you put this code? it should be on cateory template

Comment: taxonomy-product_category.php

Comment: try <?php before  } else

Comment: Yes but look it is also showing default image in that post which have featured image added